# resolve hive connection url using zookeeper

Tags: hadoop, jdbc, hive, apache-zookeeper

In my app, currently I'm connecting to hive directly using the jdbc connection string as below -

**jdbc:hive2://control-node-host:10000/default;principal=hive/_HOST@XXX?hadoop.security.credential.provider.path=jceks://hdfs@path_to_jceks_file**

Now, instead of directly connecting to hive, I want to delegate the responsibility to Zookeeper to resolve the hive url, so that if I have hive installed on 2 nodes then zookeeper can take a decision to route the connection to appropriate hive node depending on availability.

Please help if anyone has solved a similar problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. This is how it should be done -

jdbc:hive2://:/default;serviceDiscoveryMode=zooKeeper;zooKeeperNamespace=;principal=hive/_HOST@?hadoop.security.credential.provider.path=jceks://hdfs@path-to-jceks

It works.